# Once div is off screen, hide it and keep user in same position on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an effect like airbnb homepage which has a How it Works button that toggles a Div that pushes down the whole page. I was able to achieve that but after user scrolls to the bottom of the toggled div (#slideDown) and as soon as it's out of site, it disappears and user finds themselves scrolled down instead of at the top of the page once again.

Basically, I want user to be able to scroll down past the div (so it's off screen) and then stay exactly where they are on page, instead of being pushed down after the div is hidden.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c60cw8r1/

In the fiddle, it should leave you at Wrap1 when u scroll down, not by Wrap2.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideDown" style="position: relative; display: none;">
    <a class="howClose" href="#">
        <span class="screenReader">
            Close How It Works
        </span>
            ×
    </a>

</div>
  <div id="grabPromo" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#">How It Works</a></div>
<div class="site-wrapper">
  Wrap1
</div>
<div class="site-wrapper">
  Wrap2
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slideDown {
    background:#ace; 
    display: none; 
    clear: both; 
    height: 600px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;

}

.howClose {
    color: #007a87;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.screenReader {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 1px;
}   

.site-wrapper {
  height: 600px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#grabPromo').click(function(e){
    $('.site-wrapper').before( $('#slideDown') );
    $('#slideDown').slideToggle();
});

$('#closePromo').click(function(e){

    $('#slideDown').slideUp();
});

$('.howClose').click(function(e){

    $('#slideDown').slideUp();
});

var closeTop = $('.site-wrapper').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 580) {
        if ($('#slideDown').css('display') != 'none') {

            $('#slideDown').hide();
        }
        else {

        }


    }
});
```

Comment: I cannot find any fancy How it works (though I've found the link) popup, slide nothing on the airbnb page.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you see the issue I have in the fiddle? When you slide down past the div and it disappears, it slides you down even farther [screenshot for airbnb for what i see](http://imgur.com/Ms9UGDU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is occurring because when you hide your "How it works" element, the body doesn't return to it's original scroll position.

I forked your fiddle and added the effect you wanted here https://jsfiddle.net/6xkurfuj/.

I just added the line

```
$("body").scrollTop($("#wrap_1").offset().top - 20);
```

This run after the "how it works" element is hidden.